# how to to call db access method from controller to DAO class in struts

Tags: model-view-controller, struts-1

i want to call a method from controller i.e servlet. The method is located in seperate java(DAO) class. The issue is how to pass form variables from controller to java(DAO) class.

Comment: What are you asking? You call an instance method from a servlet (why is this tagged Struts 1 if you're asking about servlets?) like you do from any other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can do this by using a bean (POJO) class. I will explain it by using a simple example.

If your form has a field "UserName" , In your bean (POJO) class create a variable called UserName create getter/setter mathods  

Ex: **JSP**  

    ( User Name: <input type="text" name="UserName" value="UserName"/> )

**Bean (POJO) class :**

        public class InputBean {
            private String UserName;

            public void setUserName(String UserName) {
                this.UserName = UserName;
            }

            public String getUserName() {
                return UserName;
            }
        }

Then you can pass the form varibles from controller to DAO **by using InputBean** class (By creating InputBean Objects in both DAO and Controller) **as the intermediate class**

assume that you have a method called "add" in DAO

 public String add(inputBean inputBean) {
        // your code here
        try {
           // your code here
           //assume that database mapping class to relavent database table is User

                User task = new User();
                task.setUserName(inputBean.getUserName); //here the form data is passed
           }   

             //your code here   
    }

Then in action class you can call that method

----Action Class----

InputBean inputBean = new TaskInputBean();

 public String insert() {
      //your code here
        try {



          dao.add(inputBean);

       //your code here        

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Your getter and setter function names are incorrect and doesn't really address the OP's very confusing question.